# RenderAsync: IViewBufferScope Index was out of range when running RemoveAt

Tags: c#, .net, razorgenerator

I using IView to render some view's as string that is passed as email to someone. It runs without problem.99.9% of the time (dotnet 6)

Here is a simplistic example of what is going one there

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;

namespace MyRazor.Namespace
{
    public class MyRazor : IMyRazor
    {
        private readonly IRazorViewEngine _viewEngine;
        private readonly ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public MyRazor(
            IRazorViewEngine viewEngine,
            ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _viewEngine = viewEngine;
            _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public async Task<string> RenderViewToStringAsync<TModel>(string viewPath, TModel model,
            Action<dynamic> initializeViewBag = null)
        {
            ActionContext actionContext = new ActionContext(new DefaultHttpContext 
                { 
                    RequestServices = _serviceProvider 
                }, 
                new RouteData(), 
                new ActionDescriptor());

            IView view = _viewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewPath, isMainPage: false).View;

            using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
                    actionContext,
                    view,
                    new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(
                        metadataProvider: new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(),
                        modelState: new ModelStateDictionary())
                    {
                        Model = model,
                    },
                    new TempDataDictionary(
                        actionContext.HttpContext,
                        _tempDataProvider),
                    writer,
                    new HtmlHelperOptions());

                initializeViewBag?.Invoke(viewContext.ViewBag);
                await view.RenderAsync(viewContext);

                return writer.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

IMyRazor is registered as transient.
And sometime (3 or 4 times a day) I get

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be
> non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter
> 'index')   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.RemoveAt(Int32 index)
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Buffers.MemoryPoolViewBufferScope.GetPage(Int32
> pageSize)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Buffers.ViewBuffer.AppendNewPage()

Thing is that I cannot replicate this issue, at least not from the tests, my assumption is that `IViewBufferScope` is scoped and because `IMyRazor` is transient when I run some parallels tasks to `IMyRazor.RenderViewToStringAsync` it happens the interference between the two or more view contexts (transients) running on same scope.

Does someone have an idea how to force https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Buffers/MemoryPoolViewBufferScope.cs,fbb617c90a2880ec to fail as described above?

My test does the following (similar with what is on remote):

```
// xunit
        [Fact]
        public async Task TestFailure()
        {
            using (IServiceScope scope = testFixture.TestServer.Host.Services.CreateScope())
            {

                // Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Buffers.IViewBufferScope is scoped
                // IMyRazor is transient 
                IMyRazor builder = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyRazor>();

                List<Task<string>> tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
                tasks.Add(builder.RenderViewToStringAsync("test", new { }));
                tasks.Add(builder.RenderViewToStringAsync("test", new { }));
                tasks.Add(builder.RenderViewToStringAsync("test", new { }));
                tasks.Add(builder.RenderViewToStringAsync("test", new { }));
                tasks.Add(builder.RenderViewToStringAsync("test", new { }));
                tasks.Add(builder.RenderViewToStringAsync("test", new { }));
                tasks.Add(builder.RenderViewToStringAsync("test", new { }));
                tasks.Add(builder.RenderViewToStringAsync("test", new { }));
                tasks.Add(builder.RenderViewToStringAsync("test", new { }));
                tasks.Add(builder.RenderViewToStringAsync("test", new { }));
                tasks.Add(builder.RenderViewToStringAsync("test", new { }));
                tasks.Add(builder.RenderViewToStringAsync("test", new { }));
                tasks.Add(builder.RenderViewToStringAsync("test", new { }));
                tasks.Add(builder.RenderViewToStringAsync("test", new { }));
                tasks.Add(builder.RenderViewToStringAsync("test", new { }));
                tasks.Add(builder.RenderViewToStringAsync("test", new { }));
                tasks.Add(builder.RenderViewToStringAsync("test2", payload));

                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

                foreach (var task in tasks)
                {
                    Assert.True(task.IsCompletedSuccessfully);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I admit, I'm unable to write a test that causes the memory leak, caused by IViewBufferScope not being thread safe.

For who ever stumbles on same problem, it is explained here what is going on: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5106. Even if is for asp.net not dotnet (core), looks like the concept of one view build per scope remains unchanged even today.

Here are two solutions:

1. don't do more than one render at the same time per scope
2. get a scope for each each render async invocation, see above utility adapted to one view render per scope

   ```
    namespace MyRazor.Namespace
    {
        public class MyRazor : IMyRazor
        {
            private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

            public MyRazor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
            {
                this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
            }

            public async Task<string> RenderViewToStringAsync<TModel>(string viewPath, TModel model,
                Action<dynamic> initializeViewBag = null)
            {
                IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
                // new scope
                using (IServiceScope scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
                {

                    IRazorViewEngine viewEngine = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRazorViewEngine>();
                    ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITempDataProvider>();
                    ActionContext actionContext = new ActionContext(new DefaultHttpContext
                    {
                        RequestServices = serviceProvider
                    },
                    new RouteData(),
                    new ActionDescriptor());


                    IView view = viewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewPath, isMainPage: false).View;

                    using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
                    {
                        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
                            actionContext,
                            view,
                            new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(
                                metadataProvider: new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(),
                                modelState: new ModelStateDictionary())
                            {
                                Model = model,
                            },
                            new TempDataDictionary(
                                actionContext.HttpContext,
                                tempDataProvider),
                            writer,
                            new HtmlHelperOptions());

                        initializeViewBag?.Invoke(viewContext.ViewBag);
                        await view.RenderAsync(viewContext);

                        return writer.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ```